# Combining two json strings in Python without losing any data

Tags: python, json

I am trying to concatenate two json strings together merging the shared key lists together.

Simply combining the JSON strings does not work as you have two valid JSON strings that make an invalid JSON string. From searching the web it looks like I'll have to turn them into dictionaries and manipulate them from there.

I tried the following amongst a few other things:

```
   request = getServiceData(service, start_index, max_results) // This returns data from a valid query
   results = request.execute()

   //One attempt
   combined_results = results

   if results.get('nextLink'):
      start_index = str(int(start_index) + int(max_results))
      request = getServiceData(service, start_index, max_results)
      results = request.execute()

      new_combined_results = {}
      for k,v in results.items():
         pairs = zip(v, combined_results[k] + ['']) # add empty to avoid need for zip_longest()
         flat = (item for sub in pairs for item in sub)
         new_combined_results[k] = ''.join(flat)

      combined_results = new_combined_results 

   print json.dumps(combined_results, indent=4)
```

The error from the above gives: TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

I tried a method like this:

```
def merge(lsta, lstb):
    for i in lstb:
        for j in lsta:
            if j['name'] == i['name']:
                j.update(i)
                break
        else:
            lsta.append(i)

for k,v in dictb.items():
    merge(dicta.setdefault(k, []), v)
```

This also failed, and finally the other method I have tried is similar to:

```
z.copy(x)
z.update(y)
```

This did not work either, I can't believe it should be this difficult to merge what is essentially two dicts or just JSON (if you use json.dump).

EDIT:

As requested, here is some example data using values of start_index of 1 and max_results as 1:

Page 1:

```
{
    "kind": "analytics#gaData", 
    "rows": [
        [
            "A###", 
            "B###"
        ]
    ], 
    "containsSampledData": true, 
    "columnHeaders": [
        {
            "dataType": "STRING", 
            "columnType": "DIMENSION", 
            "name": "ga:browser"
        }, 
        {
            "dataType": "STRING", 
            "columnType": "DIMENSION", 
            "name": "ga:operatingSystem"
        }
    ], 
    "profileInfo": {
        "webPropertyId": "###", 
        "internalWebPropertyId": "###", 
        "tableId": "ga:###", 
        "profileId": "###", 
        "profileName": "###", 
        "accountId": "###"
    }, 
    "itemsPerPage": 1, 
    "totalsForAllResults": {
        "ga:pageviews": "###", 
        "ga:sessions": "###"
    }, 
    "nextLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?A###", 
    "sampleSize": "###", 
    "query": {
        "max-results": 1, 
        "dimensions": "###", 
        "start-date": "###", 
        "start-index": 1, 
        "ids": "ga:###", 
        "metrics": [
            "ga:sessions", 
            "ga:pageviews"
        ], 
        "end-date": "###"
    }, 
    "totalResults": ###, 
    "id": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/gaA###", 
    "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/gaA###", 
    "sampleSpace": "###"
}
```

Page 2:

```
{
    "kind": "analytics#gaData", 
    "rows": [
        [
            "1###", 
            "2###"
        ]
    ], 
    "containsSampledData": true, 
    "columnHeaders": [
        {
            "dataType": "STRING", 
            "columnType": "DIMENSION", 
            "name": "ga:browser"
        }, 
        {
            "dataType": "STRING", 
            "columnType": "DIMENSION", 
            "name": "ga:operatingSystem"
        }
    ], 
    "profileInfo": {
        "webPropertyId": "###", 
        "internalWebPropertyId": "###", 
        "tableId": "ga:###", 
        "profileId": "###", 
        "profileName": "###", 
        "accountId": "###"
    }, 
    "itemsPerPage": 1, 
    "totalsForAllResults": {
        "ga:pageviews": "###", 
        "ga:sessions": "###"
    }, 
    "nextLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?1###", 
    "sampleSize": "###", 
    "query": {
        "max-results": 1, 
        "dimensions": "###", 
        "start-date": "###", 
        "start-index": 1, 
        "ids": "ga:###", 
        "metrics": [
            "ga:sessions", 
            "ga:pageviews"
        ], 
        "end-date": "###"
    }, 
    "totalResults": ###, 
    "id": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga1###", 
    "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga1###", 
    "sampleSpace": "###"
}
```

Combined:

```
{
    "kind": "analytics#gaData", 
    "rows": [
        [
            "A###", 
            "B###"
        ],
        [
            "1###", 
            "2###"
        ]
    ], 
    "containsSampledData": true, 
    "columnHeaders": [
        {
            "dataType": "STRING", 
            "columnType": "DIMENSION", 
            "name": "ga:browser"
        }, 
        {
            "dataType": "STRING", 
            "columnType": "DIMENSION", 
            "name": "ga:operatingSystem"
        }
    ], 
    "profileInfo": {
        "webPropertyId": "###", 
        "internalWebPropertyId": "###", 
        "tableId": "ga:###", 
        "profileId": "###", 
        "profileName": "###", 
        "accountId": "###"
    }, 
    "itemsPerPage": 1, 
    "totalsForAllResults": {
        "ga:pageviews": "###", 
        "ga:sessions": "###"
    }, 
    "nextLink": {
        "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?A###",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?1###"
    },
    "sampleSize": "###", 
    "query": {
        "max-results": {
            ###, 
            ###
        }
        "dimensions": "###", 
        "start-date": "###", 
        "start-index": {
            ###, 
            ###
        }
        "ids": "ga:###", 
        "metrics": [
            "ga:sessions", 
            "ga:pageviews"
        ], 
        "end-date": "###"
    }, 
    "totalResults": ###, 
    "id": {
        "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/gaA###", 
        "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga1###", 
    }
    "selfLink": {
        "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/gaA###", 
        "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga1###", 
    }
    "sampleSpace": "###"
}
```

Or something like that...

Comment: `combined_results[k] + ['']` inside the zip? You are concatenating a value from `combined_results[k]` and adding with `['']` (list)

Comment: Are you assuming that the JSON attribute with a single response (such as containsSampledData) is always equivalent / to be ignored / turned into a list?

Comment: In fact, looking at the 2 inputs and the output you don't at all want to combine them - you have some that work one way some that work another such as nextLink which turns magically into a list and columnHeaders which doesn't. 

You need to Json.Loads this data and perform some manual work on mixing it this way. There is no loop that will do it out-of-the-box, Even list comprehension would need a list of parameters to do action X on and others with action Y....